# Read multine header into dictionary and data into DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, readline

I have a *.txt while the following configuration: A long header and the data preceding. See below

```
field1, field2, field3
field4, field5, field 6, field7, field8
field9, fiel10
field11, field12

1, 1.1, 1o.1
2, 0.5, 15
3, 0, 8.3
4, 2.1, 7.8
.. 
..
```

This is the code I have made. In order to save the values form the header I have created a dictionary named "header".

```
header={}
count=1
with open('file.txt') as f:
   while count<4:
      line = f.readline()
      if count==1:
         header['field1]=line.split(',')[0]
         header['field2]=line.split(',')[1]          
         header['field3]=line.split(',')[2]
      if count==2:
         header['field4]=line.split(',')[0]
         header['field5]=line.split(',')[1]          
         header['field6]=line.split(',')[2]
         header['field7]=line.split(',')[3]          
         header['field8]=line.split(',')[4]
      if count==3:
         header['field9]=line.split(',')[0]
         header['field10]=line.split(',')[1]          
      if count==4:
         header['field11]=line.split(',')[0]
         header['field12]=line.split(',')[1]          

#Read the full data into dataframe
df=  pd.read_csv('file.txt',skiprows=4,names=['Col1','Col2','Col3])
```

However, I think it is not very eficient nor elegant way to do it. I would appreciate a simpler version using the I/O file pointer or Pandas alone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the header lines, split them, and iterate over the line enries:

```
header = {}
with open('file.txt') as fobj:
    counter = 1
    for line in fobj:
        # assuming empty line between multi-line header and data
        if not line.strip():
            break
        for entry in line.split(','):
            header['field{}'.format(counter)] = entry.strip()
            counter += 1

import pprint    
pprint.pprint(header)
```

Output:

```
{'field1': 'field1',
 'field10': 'fiel10',
 'field11': 'field11',
 'field12': 'field12',
 'field2': 'field2',
 'field3': 'field3',
 'field4': 'field4',
 'field5': 'field5',
 'field6': 'field 6',
 'field7': 'field7',
 'field8': 'field8',
 'field9': 'field9'}
```